# Opening and Closing of window in Ext JS 3.3

Tags: javascript, extjs

Opening and Closing WIndow

I have a window called from a grid that launches a window, If I launch just one window, I can drag it any where I want, but If I open the same window twice it becomes undraggable, how do I resolve this. Also if I call a close operation on this window, it closes just one of the window and leaves the other. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Can you post some relevant code and maybe a screenshot of how the window looks the second time you open it?

Answer (score 0):

```
              Ext.Window({
                title:id.text,
                autoHeight: true,
                width: 500,
                id:'form1',
                resizable: false,
                plain:true,

                y: 100,
                autoScroll: true,

                //layout: 'fit',
                buttonAlign:'center',
                items: [{
                    xtype:'form1'
                }],
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: function(){

                    }
                },{
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function(){

                    }
                }]


            });
```

Comment: The windows sit at the same location as the first, but when I close the the window, there is anoder window beneath it and it becomes undraggable